# System Sounds not working as expected. Gnome 3.18.5. Ubuntu Mate

Tags: gnome, sound, login, 16.10, mate

I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.10 with gnome 3.18.5. Recently I had installed the arc theme for gnome. I had also installed some extensions. All was fine, until I noticed that the desktop login sound wasn't playing anymore. Also some notification sounds like plugging/unplugging the usb isn't playing. Couldn't find any relevant solutions. Please help.